# Auto Print multi page word document to pdf

Tags: python, printing

I'm have a pdf file with 100 pages, every page is a document with different individual names. Is it possible to code using python to print the pdf page by page so that the output will have 100 different pdf?

Comment: Stack overflow don't provide you complete answer.Can you share what you have written till now ?

Answer (score 0):

This code will split one PDF with multiple pages into multiple files.

```
import os
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter


def pdf_splitter(path):
    fname = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(path))[0]

    pdf = PdfFileReader(path)
    for page in range(pdf.getNumPages()):
        pdf_writer = PdfFileWriter()
        pdf_writer.addPage(pdf.getPage(page))

        output_filename = '{}_page_{}.pdf'.format(
            fname, page+1)

        with open(output_filename, 'wb') as out:
            pdf_writer.write(out)

        print('Created: {}'.format(output_filename))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    path = 'C:\\your_path\
```

\test.pdf'
    pdf_splitter(path)